# UX.SE Netherlands meetup

Tags: discussion

There are quite a few people on UX who appear to live in the Netherlands. Would it be interesting to organise a meetup for us somewhere central, eg. Amsterdam or Utrecht? Would you be interested in attending or helping to organise something like that?

Comment: @JohnGB and I did a spontaneous two person meetup today! A+ would do again.

Comment: Let me know if you ever end up planning an official one :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to this particular Stack site, but might be interested as well. My location is Utrecht, but Amsterdam/The Hague/Rotterdam etc are all doable as well. Will keep track of this thread, let's see how many more people are interested.